# how to sort all the 1500 rational numbers (which are in the two unequal rows in excel sheet) using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, sorting

i have 100 excel files each consisting of 1500 rational numbers which have no column titles.in each file ,First row contains 1000 numbers and second row contains 500 numbers.First I want to sort all the values of one excel file (1500 numbers) in ascending order.I tried pandas and am able to sort only one coloumn.how can i sort all the values in ascending order?.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1vjh.png

Comment: Did you try `header=None`? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Yes.But still I am lacking the sorting out

Comment: What have you tried? Did none of the results you got when you googled `sort pandas dataframe` help?

Comment: 'orders.sort_index(axis=1)'  -this worked for 1st row only..........                    
  'sorted_orders = orders.sort_index(ascending=True)'      -this and others i have tried.but not working